# PayPalCheckoutSdk - Doesn't accept credit cards?

Tags: php, paypal

I just implemented this: **PHP PayPalCheckoutSdk**:
https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

It redirects visitor to PayPal login and then he pays.

**But my customer wants clients to pay using credit card and only optionally use PayPal login.**

I've read there's another API that uses Javascript called **Smart Payments** (or Express Checkout, i have no clue...):

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Visitor can choose to pay using Credit Card, and this works as expected, but this is done using Javascript and so customer inputs the Credit Card information inside the actual eshop website!
**Is it possible to redirect the customer to PayPal, so that he inputs the CC information there?**

---

For Credit Card payments PayPal suggests using **braintreegateway.com,** which seems like a separate company. It has a separate API keys and administration (transaction list) meaning the transactions are separate from PayPal account!

Answer (score 1):

A lot to unpack here.

The simplest way to accept credit cards is [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) -- which can be implemented *with or without* a server-side SDK to create and capture the order. Creating and capturing the order on a server is much more robust for order management.

The client-side JS portion of it provides a black "Debit or Credit Card" button, which can typically be used without any login.

---

Other, different services for processing credit cards that are also offered by PayPal are [Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments,](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/) and the [Braintree Direct Gateway](https://www.braintreepayments.com/products/braintree-direct). These require more work to integrate, and the business account needs to be approved for the service to be set up and available to it.

Comment: "Set up standard payments" always shows the BUTTONS on client website, that is inconvenient for what my client wanted (that is to be redirected to PayPal and customer would enter the CC info there).

Comment: Redirection to PayPal site in order for the customer to pay there using Credit Card is probably not possible... I have no clue why PayPal didn't make that available. Thank you for your information.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Why would your client want to redirect away? The PayPal buttons for entering information w/o a redirect are 100% preferable in every respect. There is no contest.

Comment: All payment gateways in Czech republic work this way, meaning you redirect the client to payment gateway and he enters CC info there. It's 100% preferable for the customer to input his important CC numbers inside a known banking company rather than unknown eshop website, that might be potentially scamming the client/stealing his CC info.